# Generating python CLI man page

Tags: python, command-line-interface, manpage

I am developing a python CLI tool (using [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/optparse.html) in python2.6, but hope to switch soon to python2.7) and I am about to write the man page.
I have some experience on generating dynamic man pages by:

- creating a dedicated method that composes a string in [pod format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Documentation) and writes it to a file
- executing the [pod2man](http://man.he.net/man1/pod2man) command to generate data in groff format to be passed to the man command

I would also like to generate wiki pages with the same content as the man page (with pod I can generate html through [pod2html](http://man.he.net/man1/pod2html), and probably the html can be easily translated into wiki format).
Has someone a better idea/flow on how to do this?

One thing I have found as interesting is on this link: [Creating Man Pages Using optparse and distutils](http://andialbrecht.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/creating-a-man-page-with-distutils-and-optparse/)

Comment: POD is for perl; trying to use it in python code might get ugly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual way to generate documentation in Python is to use [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/). For example, that's what's used in the official Python documentation. Once you have a Sphinx documentation project set up (see  [this tutorial](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/index.html)), you can generate man pages from your Sphinx documentation files via `make man`. You should also [alter the configuration](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-manual-page-output) in `conf.py` to produce appropriate output.

(It's worth noting that while Sphinx is the usual tool for writing documentation in Python, that doesn't mean it's the usual tool for generating man pages. Use what you want!)

Answer (score 6):

While sphinx is a really great documentation system, it's awfully complex and hard to master. If you need a bang solution, I suggest you look in my project [build_manpage.py](https://github.com/pwman3/pwman3/blob/d718a01fa8038893e42416b59cdfcda3935fe878/build_manpage.py).

It is *not* a replacement for properly documenting you projects (with sphinx or what ever way you choose). But it has some immediate benefits for a Python programmer:

- You don't have to learn the `man` syntax.
- You don't have to learn `rst` syntax (never the less, you should one day learn it ...)
- You don't need to maintain your optparser\argparser *and* a man page formated in external file (in man, rst, or any other conversion system).
- You simply add one file to you build configuration, and a man page is created for you!

If you do want to use a more complicated system, with a lot of bells and whistles, sphinx allows you convert an `rst` formated page to man page. And a recently young project, takes a similar approach to my parser and scans your `ArgumentParser` to produce an `rst` formatted page,with sphinx directives (such that you don't need to write it yourself.
(In contrast my scanner produces a man page directly).

Note that this is now part of a [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/1169) to [add a manpage formatter in the standard library](https://bugs.python.org/issue14102).

Comment: Looks like you have disbanded your project, it's 404.

Comment: @SummerBreeze, it's inside the setup.py or in older revisions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `click` you can use [click-man](https://github.com/timofurrer/click-man).
It can generate man pages from click applications.

Answer (score 0):

> One thing I have found as interesting is on this link: Creating Man Pages Using optparse and distutils

As a direct follow-up to the post you mentioned:
There's now a possibility to use the [argparse-manpage](https://pypi.org/project/argparse-manpage/) project.