# Can pydoc be used to generate manpages?

Tags: python, documentation-generation, manpage, pydoc

I have a set of python scripts that I would like to create manpages for. They are documented with docstrings, so I can get at the documentation that way, but I would also like to have manpages.

Is there a way to use pydoc to generate *roff sources for manpages?

edit: Something like perl's pod2man for python.

Comment: What about [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), it also generates man pages.

Comment: That's something to look at, thanks!

Comment: See this question: [Generating python CLI man page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7176560)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) is not generating manpages, just showing docs in a form of man page:

> ...in a style similar to the manual pages shown by the Unix man command...

You can save it by:

```
pydoc sys >sys-docs.txt
```

or with terminal "colours" (use `less` to render them):

```
PAGER="cat>sys-docs.txt" pydoc sys
```